# Unable to decrypt password in Jhipster

Tags: spring, jhipster

I have working on jhipster.but i am unable to decrypt password in jhipster and Spring.PasswordEncoderClass only provide encode and Match password function.can you help to decrypt password in jhipster.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are using Spring Security's [StandardPasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/StandardPasswordEncoder.html), I do hope you can't decrypt it :-)

We are indeed storing hashed passwords: as you say, you can encode a password, and validate (match) if a specific String is the correct password, but you can't decrypt it. This means that if your database is stolen by a hacker, he would have a very hard time to figure out your users' passwords.

So this is a very good idea if you want to keep your users' password secure.

If, however, you want to have your passwords in plain text, you can change the encoder in your SecurityConfiguration class: you need to change the "passwordEncoder" bean, and probably use Spring Security's "NoOpPasswordEncoder" class. Of course, I have never done it, as I care about my users' data :-)

Comment: @julien-dubois I'm not seeing a salt column in the `JHI_USER` table. Where does the salt come from?

Comment: Ah, got it. As it uses a random salt internally it is stored in the same column.